# Save attachments to a google drive folder from each email id respectively

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script that can save all attachments sent by an email id from time to time to a particular drive folder.

I am new to GAS and found this script however it doesn't seem to fit my requirement. Can anyone help, Please??

```
      function GmailToDrive() {
var query = '';
query = 'in:inbox from:noreply@agyo.io has:nouserlabels ';
var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
var label = getGmailLabel_(labelName);
var parentFolder;
if (threads.length > 0) {
    parentFolder = getFolder_(folderName);
}
var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
for (var i in threads) {
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j in mesgs) {
        //get attachments
        var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
        var message_body = mesgs[j].getBody();
        for (var k in attachments) {
            var attachment = attachments[k];
            var isDefinedType = checkIfDefinedType_(attachment);
            if (!isDefinedType) continue;
            var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
            var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
            file.setName(renameFile_(attachment, message_body))
            parentFolder.addFile(file);
            root.removeFile(file);
        }
    }
    threads[i].addLabel(label);
}
```

}

I am unable to understand the usage of  getFolder_(folderName) and checkIfDefinedType_(attachment);

All I need is this:
Create a new folder when a new email sends me attachments and save them to that folder...

Comment: My guess is that `checkIfDefinedType_ and getFolder_` are unique functions defined by the original author.  You will need to go back and get them or rewrite them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

The code you provided is using several functions which are not defined (`getGmailLabel_`, `getFolder_`, `checkIfDefinedType_`, `renameFile_`). Their definitions should probably be wherever you first found this script.

#### Goal and solution:

In any case, based on the goal you mentioned, none of these non-defined functions is actually needed:

> save all attachments sent by an email id from time to time to a particular drive folder

- No need to get labels (`getGmailLabel_`), since you just want to retrieve attachments from messages between certain dates, and don't want to add any label to any message.
- If you want to retrieve the threads between certain dates, you should use the search operators `before:` and `after:` (see [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)).
- You can retrieve your desired folder by doing [DriveApp.getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) (if you don't know how to get the folder `id` for a specific folder, this `id` is part of the folder URL, as shown [here](https://ploi.io/documentation/database/where-do-i-get-google-drive-folder-id). If you want to look for name instead, just use [DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename) and loop through it with [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) and [next()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator#next()) to find your desired folder.
- There's no reason to use `getRootFolder`, since you can create the file directly to your desired folder via [Folder.createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob).
- Not sure why `checkIfDefinedType_` is used, but that's not necessary to create the corresponding file in Drive.
- By default the created file will have the same name as the attachment, but in any case you can customize it with `file.setName(attachment.getName() + " WHATEVER CUSTOM STRING YOU WANT TO ADD");`.

#### Code snippet:

```
function GmailToDrive() {
  const query = 'from:noreply@agyo.io before:2021-05-04 after:2021-05-01'; // Set sender and dates you prefer
  const threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("YOUR_FOLDER_ID");
  threads.forEach(thread => {
    const mesgs = thread.getMessages();
    mesgs.forEach(message => {
      const attachments = message.getAttachments();
      attachments.forEach(attachment => {
        const attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        const file = folder.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        file.setName(attachment.getName() + " CREATED IN DRIVE");
      });
    });
  });
}
```